# Tkinter: super().__init__() produces AttributeError while tk.Entry.__init__() does not, even though they're both utilizing the same base class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, attributeerror

I'm currently learning Tkinter and I'm struggling to understand why a call to `super().__init__()` results in an attribute error but calling the `__init__()` method from the superclass directly does not.

```py
class DirEntry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
```

This code produces the following error:

```py
AttributeError: 'DirEntry' object has no attribute 'tk'`
```

When I switch the following line:

```py
super().__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
```

to

```py
tk.Event.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
```

Everything seems to work fine.

All of the explanations I've seen say the difference between `super().__init__()` and calling the parent class `__init__()` is only meaningful during multiple inheritance, so I'm not sure I understand why this behaviour is happening.

Does anyone have any insights into this? Maybe I'm doing something wrong syntactically?

Here is the full sample of my code. This is just a toy program, so there's not much purpose to what I'm building other to just muck about and explore how to build something with Tkinter.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as f

class DirEntry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)


class GUI:

    def __init__(self):
        self.main_window = tk.Tk()
        self.main_window.geometry('500x200')

        self.input_dir_string = tk.StringVar()

        self.input_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.main_window,
                                         text='Input Directory')

        self.input_dir = DirEntry(self.input_frame,
                                  textvariable=self.input_dir_string,
                                  width=40)

        self.button = tk.Button(self.input_frame,
                                text='Choose',
                                command=self.ask_dir)

        self.input_frame.pack()
        self.input_dir.pack(side='left')
        self.button.pack(side='left')

        tk.mainloop()

    def ask_dir(self):
        self.input_dir_string.set(fd.askdirectory())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui = GUI()
```

Comment: You're not supposed to pass `self` to `super().__init__`.

Comment: Oh gosh, I can't believe it was something so small. Thank you very much.